# Can I reduce this with For/Next Loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I feel like there should be a way to increment this with a for next loop. I want to make the shapes visible based on the cell value in C36. Is there a way to increment the shapes name for each iteration as well as the value?  I would like to use 100 of these Oval shapes so I'm hoping something like this will work. Or, any other ideas of course.

Rediculous amount of code:

`Me.Shapes("OVAL 1").Visible = Range("C36").Value > 0
 Me.Shapes("OVAL 2").Visible = Range("C36").Value > 1
 Me.Shapes("OVAL 3").Visible = Range("C36").Value > 3`
Etc...

Hopefully something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim i as Integer, x as Integer
 For i = 1 to 100
  For x - 0 to 99
     Me.Shapes("OVAL " & i).Visible = Range("C36").Value > x
  Next x
 Next i
End Sub`
```

Comment: Note: You must be getting a compile time error in this line - `For x - 0 to 99`. Replace `-` with `=`

Comment: I don't see why you are nesting 2 loops. For each i, the only meaningful assignment to the `Visible` property is the last one at x = 99, so essentially, your test is always `Range("C36").Value > 99`.

Comment: The x - 0 - 99 was a type.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I wasn't sure how to increment both the object and the value.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to show only those shapes for which the value at C36 is larger than their numeric suffix minus one. If so, you could go along those lines:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 100
        'Shape will be visible if a value at C36 on this worksheet is larger
        'than (the shape's index suffix minus one).
        Me.Shapes("OVAL " & i).Visible = Me.Range("C36").Value > (i - 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

For a bit more performance, read the value at C36 into a variable of type `double`, **before** the loop, and use it within the loop.

Comment: Awesome!  That's exactly what I was looking for. I added a msgbox to the code above to see the values of x & i and it was incrementing x to 100 before stepping i to 2.  The x - 0 - 100 was a typo. Thanks for pointing that out Gurman